# how to get value from an array

Tags: php

how to get the value 4500 to a variable

```
stdClass Object ( [total] => 4500 )
```

i tried like these

```
$abc['total']
$abc->total
```

when i print the $abc->total

i got

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 4500 ) )

please help me

Comment: Please post all the code involved in reproducing the error, plus the error message itself.

Comment: If `$abc` is an object of this class, then `$abc->total` should work. What is the error? And btw. the variable is not an array but an object so `$abc['total']` won't work anyway.

Comment: what is the $abc ?  Is it a object ?

Comment: Can please clearly specify which command prints out which information. Still, it is absolutely unclear what `$abc` or `$abc->total` really is. Also, which PHP version are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since you are not giving a large part of the PHP code i assume that code is correctly printed out

this answer works fine:

```
<?php
$abc = array('total' => 4500); // I've created an array with key='total' and val=4500
$abc = (object)$abc; // returns stdClass Object ( [total] => 4500 ) 
echo $abc->total; // it should print 4500
?>
```

Comment: but i got error like
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$total

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $abc->total
```

should work.

If you want to output the value in a string, enclose it in [curly brackets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to be on the safe side:

```
echo "Value is {$abc->total}";
```

or use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
echo 'Value is ' . $abc->total;
```